# VS402375: Can't find the process associated with team project

Tags: tfs

I'm getting this error while trying to access Administration Page of my collection:﻿﻿
[Administratio Page ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN7z3.jpg)

I tried upload TFS.Configuration database, but no success so far.

This is the results of my sql selects:
[SQL SELECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isnx7.jpg)

Comment: You absolutely **should not** change values in any of the TFS databases without explicit instruction from Microsoft to do so. You run the risk of damaging your installation and leaving yourself in a totally unrecoverable state.

Comment: Hi, Fabio Moura any update on this issue? Did my reply helped or gave a right direction?

Comment: We restored database backup and everything went fine, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the error info `VS402375: Can't find the process associated with team project 'xxx'. Contact support to resolve this error.`

It looks like the process template (which you used for the project) is missing in the team project collection database.

A solution is restoring your back-up database, which may do the trick for this issue. *Daniel* is right, it's highly not recommend to modify TFS databases yourself.

Another solution is manually changing the templateID  to match what your collection. More detail steps please take a look at *bmonwai's* answer in this similar [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/a31160d4-0bca-4d94-8444-6cd0f4f01da4/cant-access-collection-admin-page-after-detach-reattach?forum=tfsgeneral).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post, but this also occurs if you have Extensions installed and then move from one database to another (backup/restore)
When you are attaching the collection, this would have given you a notification that is has dependant extensions. If you ignore this and continue, when you try to get to the admin page for that collection you can get this error as well.
I would recommend either installing the dependant extensions OR prior to detaching the collections at source, ensure you remove/uninstall the extensions.
Usually, installing the required extensions can solve this.